# can gnuplot point the z axis to left or right?

Tags: plot, 3d, gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot, and am using it to draw 3d plots.  I would expect gnuplot should be able to orient the xyz coordinate system in any orientation, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  The z axis appears constrained to be in a vertical plane perpendicular the screen of my monitor.  In other words, I cannot get the z axis to point at all to the left or right.  Is this possible, and if so how is it done?  I will try to include an image of a 3d plot made with Mathcad that shows what I mean.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYMVN.gif)

Comment: Please include see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Good luck.

Comment: i think it's not possible, but you may just rotate the resulting image after you saved it (from the command-line)...

Comment: That feature is available only in the current development version https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/patches/737/